# Can a domain service inject multiple repositories or operate with different aggregate roots?

Tags: domain-driven-design, domainservices

Can a domain service inject multiple repositories or operate with different aggregate roots? If yes, would it be considered a violation of the SRP principle?

I am looking in depth and I have this question regarding domain services. If I have a business logic that involves working with several Aggregate Roots, what would be the best way to solve it with a Domain Service?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Can a domain service inject multiple repositories or operate with different aggregate roots?

I see no problem with this as I find that working with multiple aggregates is usually where you need a domain service since the functionality doesn't seem to fit on a particular aggregate.  If the service does not fetch the relevant objects then they could be passed in from the integration/application concern.  In fact, you probably want to start there: a method that accepts the relevant aggregates.  You may find that it makes more sense to retrieve the objects in the caller before invoking the service method.

> If yes, would it be considered a violation of the SRP principle?

The SRP is about what your class does and not what it uses so unless you are adding more functionality than is required I don't see how SRP is negatively affected.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. And in the case of an application service? Should/could this inject different repositories to provide the different ARs to the domain service? Or should it be done differently? In a CQRS scenario I understand that it is better to inject the QueryBus instead of another application service or repositoriy to retrieve information from other modules.

Comment: An application service usually deals with *ids* and retrieves the relevant *objects*.  Those are then passed to the domain service.  Yes, you could inject the dependencies but if there are too many you may opt for a mediator.  I know that Jimmy Bogard's `MediatR` is quite popular but I have my [own implementation](https://github.com/Shuttle/Shuttle.Core.Mediator) that isn't dependent on interfaces.  In any event, when it comes to wiring dependencies we need to be pragmatic I guess.  But use the mechanism/technique you are comfortable with.